# how can I recognize multiple faces from one image in python

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, deep-learning

I wants to create an app which can recognize multiple faces from one image, I planed to built an android app through `KIVI`, I am not getting from where to start, it is my first minor project, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you perform object detection to find potential faces, and then you perform face recognition on the face(s) detected.

This article walks through the various steps quite well:
https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78

The author also has a Python library that does recognition of multiple faces in a scene with video examples:
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are so many ways for doing so depending on your point of view. You can use deep learning and machine learning approaches or old fashioned vision approaches. For instance, you can use `Segnet` neural net if you want to use learning approaches. But because you have limited computation power, vision approaches is more common. Take a look at [here](https://www.superdatascience.com/opencv-face-detection/).